# SMCQL practical examples

Tags: secret-sharing, multiparty-computation, data-privacy, differential-privacy

I am looking for some practical examples on how to use [SMCQL](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=https://www.vldb.org/pvldb/vol10/p673-rogers.pdf&ved=2ahUKEwjW8L6NjLj8AhXkwzgGHXLvBXsQFnoECBcQAQ&usg=AOvVaw2q9zK1Pqvo1o2g_SHZH_-c) on some typical SQL queries. The paper seems to be oriented more towards theory. Can somebody point me to some examples to understand it better? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can check there github repo here [link](https://github.com/smcql), there is few examples of queries. You can use your own database and queries if you want, the documentation explains is it all.